# convert TextInput to uppercase with react-native

Tags: react-native

I have an `onChangeText` that converts the text to uppercase when I'm writing, but the moment I start to delete some of the writing, the text begins to be duplicated.

```js
<TextInput
placeholderTextColor="gray" value={name}
onChangeText={(text) => setName(text.toUpperCase())}
selectionColor="orange"
autoCapitalize='none'
autoCorrect={false}
selectTextOnFocus={false}
/>
```

Comment: Just tries your code on a react-native app, and everything seems to work fine (No duplication occurred). Can you provide more information about your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason it duplicates its because when you make setName after on change to a different value it triggers onChangeText again so your code executes twice.
Instead you can use onKeyPress event and capitalize keys.
Prepared a snack for you:
https://snack.expo.dev/@robertoyoc/autocapitalize-input

```
       onKeyPress={(event) => {
          const {key} = event.nativeEvent;
          switch (key) {
            case 'Backspace':
              setName((current) => current.slice(0, -1));
              break;
            default:
              setName((current) => `${current}${key.toUpperCase()}`)
          }
        }}
```

This is the general concept, you probably need to add some exceptions to the switch statement

Comment: Good morning, when trying to delete delete something when writing in the example you sent, "BACKSPACE" begins to appear

Comment: On the cell phone when I already generate the apk it does not allow me to add space in the text